# git: change of one branch is showed in another branch

Tags: git

I made some local change of file1.txt in master branch. Then I switch to another branch: "git checkout another_branch",
And then I run "git status". It showed "modified: file1.txt"
And when I view file1.txt. the file is changed.

Shouldn't change of one branch do not touch another branch?

Comment: I guess you commited the change of said file in master, right?

Comment: I did not. after git commit, the change dissappeared after I switch to another_branch. now I know the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made the change to file1.txt but did not commit the change, it will stay locally even if you switch branches.

If you meant to include the change on your master branch, make sure you commit your change. For example:

```
$ git add file1.txt
$ git commit -m "Change to file1.txt"
$ git checkout another_branch
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I did not commit that is the reason. from the answer I conclude that although I can create different branches in order to work on different features. If they require to change the same file, then do not work on them the same time

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve committed your changes on the master branch and you’ve checked out on a new branch from master it will have those changes on your new branch..

Or another possibility you haven’t committed your changes on the master branch.. your changes will still show if you checkout on a new branch

Comment: Thanks I did not git commit that is the reason.  from the answer I conclude that although I can create different branches in order to work on different features. If they require to change the same file, then do not work on them the same time